# What is System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I have below lines of code in a project which is built on MVC3 and is using StructureMap.

```
var serviceLocator = new StructureMapServiceLocator(container);
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(serviceLocator);
```

I have read MSDN docs on DependencyResolver but still not able to understand it.

What exactly does above two lines do for me ?

Answer (score 0):

This is class implementing [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) technique.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a IoC container like StructureMap, it means the dependencies, in this case the controllers, will be resolved using the IoC container, rather than being newed up per request.